# How to ignore `permission denied` errors for `iframe` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon, permission-denied

Problem description: I am providing `iframe` to third party pages to implement it in their pages. My `iframe` opens webapp in their pages. I have set up error reporting and can get every error which happens with my webapp in this `iframe`. Now I am getting error only from one client (always same IP, on FireFox) - [Error: Permission denied to access property "x"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied)

Tested my webapp on FireFox and everything works as expected, it's seems like this error comes from some FireFox add-on (which third party page's client uses) which tries to access some property in my `iframe`.

I know that it's valid case to not allow cross domain access because it is a security issue and both apps have to be on same origin, but that would be case if this error comes from parent page which my third party friends can change. Right now it's unpredictable and not maintainable because comes from extensions.

Question: I am worried if there are any solution to ignore error like that which comes from client's extensions or just ignore those error at all in `iframe`? Because I can't control what client is set up in its side.

Comment: You can use `try/catch` to catch errors in your own code. I don't think there's much you can do when the error is happening in someone else's code.

Comment: Hmm, seems like this will not be a case. Just want to avoid possibility to access properties in `iframe` from root level or somehow ignore those cases. In result of that this error would not be happened and reported and app keeps working as expected.

Comment: Why does the third-party page trying to access something in your iframe cause your application to report an error? The error should be happening only in their code.